# Deleting Empty rows in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete Empty rows by using below code:

```
worksheet.Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

The code above is working fine, but giving `run time error '1004': No Cells were found.`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
On Error Resume Next
worksheet.Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
On Error GoTo 0
```

The error handling helps when there are no blank cells. `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` will always return an error if there are no cells like that so error handling is the only way (that I know of) to deal with it if you want to use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`.

Comment: Explaining what these extra lines do exactly would help a lot :-)

Answer (score 8):

You need to test that there are any blanks.

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Worksheet.Columns("A:A")) > 0 Then
    Worksheet.Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

You can just use On Error Resume Next to skip over the line if there are no blanks, but it's generally preferable to test for a specific condition, rather than assuming you know what the error will be.

As far as I can see you'd only get the "No Cells Found" message if every cell in Column A has a value.

EDIT: Based on @brettdj's comments, here's an alternative that still uses CountBlank:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Intersect(worksheet.UsedRange, ws.Columns("A:A"))) > 0 Then
    worksheet.Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Of course UsedRange is notoriously fickle and may be bigger than it appears.  I think it's best to first determine the actual range where the rows are to be deleted and then check the SpecialCells in that range, e.g.:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells) > 0 Then
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

One last note - I changed the variable from "worksheet" to "ws" as "worksheet" is an Excel reserved word.

Comment: Doug, that code will still fail for the OPs question as CountBlank as used above ill look at every cell in column A - so its a virtual certainty that this condition is always True. Whereas SpecialCells looks just at the usedrange, and there may be no blank cells, ie _"As far as I can see you'd only get the "No Cells Found" message if every cell in Column A has a value"_ is incorrect

Comment: brettdj, thanks for the info.  I wondered about the fact that the OP was using it on the full column, and now I understand how that might work.

Comment: Cheers Doug. SpecialCells could be explained more intuitively that it is.

Answer (score 2):

Working fine with me . These statement does not throw any error to me

```
 Sheet1.Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete 'perfect
```

I found these type of solution for your question

```
 On Error Resume Next
 Sheet1.Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
 On Error GoTo 0
```

Take a look at these links

http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming/390329-microsoft-visual-basic-run-time-error-1004-no-cells-were-found.html

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=343744

and well yes did you set your object ? worksheet does not make any sense here

```
dim wsheet as worksheets
set wsheet = worksheets("worksheetname") or worksheets("sheet1")
wsheet.Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: +1 for the error handling suggestion. And I agree that "worksheet" is not the best variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
If Range("Table2").Rows.Count > 1 Then
   Range("Table2").EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub delete_rows_blank()

t = 1
lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Do Until t = lastrow
If Cells(t, "A") = "" Then
Rows(t).Delete
End If
t = t + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Consider adding more to explain what the code is doing.

Comment: sorry - the macro just loops through column "A" for empty cells and deletes row if so. (you can adjust lastrow or column letter to match your needs). Hope this helps ! :)