# Excel VBA cut and paste a dynamic range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with product names in column A which alternate product name, blank row, product name, blank row etc. However the starting row in column A as well as how many products and therefore blank rows is variable.

I'm trying to write some code so that I can reformat the data to not have any blank rows in it, but am getting stuck on a way to delete the appropriate number of blank rows. Here is what I have so far:

```
Dim i as long
Dim j as long
i = Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

Do Until i = 1
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
i = i - 1
Loop
```

The i index gets the number of non-blank rows in column A. My plan was to then loop i-1 times to delete the blank rows.

This loop doesn't quite work though since when a row is Deleted and I End(xlDown) I go to the top of the items in the row rather than the bottom.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379673/excel-vba-delete-empty-rows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876340/deleting-empty-rows-in-excel-using-vba