# Custom Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to accomplish a few things in my macro.  Here are what those are.

1. Sort by column B.
2. Add a blank line if Column B is different from the previous row
3. If column K is blank delete the row.
4. If column K equals "Purchase order" sort those rows by date in column O
5. If column K equals "Planned order sort those rows by date in column P

The only two values in column K will be Purchase order or Planned order once the blank ones are removed.  I can't figure out how I can sort only a certain amount of rows based on value of another row.  Any help would be appreciated.  I have tried some of it and continuing to get no where and have not found other examples similar online.

```
Sub InsertRows()
  Dim lastRow As Long
  Dim rowPtr As Long
 
  lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  For rowPtr = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    If Not IsEmpty(Range("B" & rowPtr)) Then
      If Range("B" & rowPtr) <> Range("B" & rowPtr - 1) Then
        Range("B" & rowPtr).EntireRow.Insert
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Initial example data.

[image: Initial Data]
Formatted results
[image: Formatted Results]

Comment: If a new row added in point 2, after it in point 3 it will immediately removed.

Comment: Maybe you should display an example of your data and how it should look like.

Comment: @FunThomas just added images of before after data.  Hopefully it will help

Comment: Is the empty row really needed or do you use it just for optical reasons? I usually tend to use conditional formatting to draw a line between groups.

Comment: @FunThomas It is needed.  I have to format this weekly for a client and that is their preference for when I send it on to them.  There are usually 400-660 rows and maybe 40-60 items so it is a bit time consuming.

Comment: Can it be that you mixed up the columns for what you list on point 4 and 5? Your example data has empty values in column O for *"planned order"*. Btw: Is the column always empty for *"planned order"*?

Comment: @FunThomas yes I did mix up those columns. Sorry for the confusion and yes it will be blank for planned orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should think about the order of your tasks. I guess a better order is the following.

1. Delete all rows where column K is empty.
2. Sort your data
3. Add a blank line if Column B is different from the previous row

Step 1 is easy. I borrowed the logic from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7877099/7599798

```
With ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    .Columns("K:K").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    (...)
```

Step 2 (Sorting) is also easy if you think about the logic: You sort by B, then K (descending, so that *Purchasing* comes before *Planned*), then O and then P (assuming that O is always empty the K = "planned order"). As for the planned column O is always empty, it doesn't affect the order.

```
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = .Range("A2:O" & lastrow)

    With .Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=r.Columns(2), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=r.Columns(11), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=r.Columns(15), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=r.Columns(16), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
        
        .SetRange r
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

And for Step 3 you already have the code. I just used `Cells` instead of `Range`, but that's a matter of taste.

```
    Dim rowPtr as long
    For rowPtr = lastRow To 3 Step -1
        If .Cells(rowPtr, "B") <> .Cells(rowPtr - 1, "B") Then
            .Cells(rowPtr, "B").EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next

End With
```

Comment: This worked great.  Only have one very weird thing not working.  For some reason the first line after running it is a planned order but then after that the rest of it is sorted properly.  Not a huge deal as I can move that one line but just thought I would see if it was a small tweak needed.  The logic seems fine so not sure why it is happening.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. When your range to be sorted starts at row 2 (that's how the variable `r` is set) and you set `.Header = xlYes`, the row 2 is seen as header row and therefore stays at it's position. Just update the line to `.Header = xlNo` (I updated the code in the answer)